# Optimal values of x to get smoothest curve f(x) given N points

Tags: arrays, interpolation, sampling

Suppose I have a function, y = x^2, and I'm allowed to plot 10 points between -1 and 1. Which values of x should I choose to have the smoothest curve?

Is there a standard way to do this? Clearly you'll have more points near x = 0. I'm guessing I need to consider the second derivative here.

Comment: The second derivative of a second degree equation is a constant. I don't think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

More precisely, you need to consider the curvature of the curve. Since we will require second derivative in order to compute the curvature, so what you said about 'considering the second derivative' is in the right direction.

For your curve y=x^2, the curvature is

```
   2
----------- 
(1+4x^2)^1.5
```

This means that the curvature attains its maximum value 2.0 at x=0.0 and will become smaller as |x| gets bigger. So, you do need to have more points around x=0.0. From my experience, if you are able to sample the points along the curve so that they have equal arc length in between each two points, the resulting polyline will be a good approximation to the original curve. However, I am not sure whether it will be the 'smoothest' or not.